# Split second column of two column data set and append to botom

Tags: google-bigquery

[image]

So I have two columns of data of the form above. The first column is just a single EAN but the second column can have comma or underscore separated ASIN values.

I would like to split each ASIN in the ASIN column and then append it to the bottom of the data set alongside its corresponding EAN (and replace the original row).

So for row 68 below the appended data to the bottom would be:

738678181690   B00EUTKDQS

738678181690   B000KEIPC6

738678181690   B01IAEN1PI

And this will replace the original row 68 so that that doesn't exist anymore. How can I do this? I tried using SPLIT() and OFFSET but run into various issues. I guess the solution is to use UNNEST() but not very skilled at flattening arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of SPLIT() to create an array for rows where ASIN has commas. Then simply unnest that array:

```
SELECT EAN, ASIN2 FROM your_table, unnest(split(ASIN, ",") ) as asin2
```

Complete demo:

```
WITH testTable AS (
  SELECT * FROM unnest([struct(12345 as EAN, "A,B,C" as ASIN), 
struct(234 as EAN, "B23" as ASIN), struct(4 as EAN, "BC3" as ASIN)])
)

SELECT EAN, ASIN2 FROM testTable, unnest(split(ASIN, ",") ) as asin2
```

Comment: How can I amend the code above to make it work with my situation? I ran the code above and it does successfully split the ASIN but specifically with the context you defined but not sure how to amend the datatype syntax so it works.